# Asp.Net Core docker-compose https self signed certificate issue

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I am not able to run docker-compose for an asp.net core 3 api on https with a self signed cert.  I have followed the instructions on ms docs but I have given up at this point after trying everything for hours:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-https?view=aspnetcore-2.2

```
dotnet dev-certs https -ep %USERPROFILE%\.aspnet\https\aspnetapp.pfx -p { password here }
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

My docker compose is here:

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  localdev:
    name: localdev
    
services:
  main-api:
    container_name: main-api
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    #restart: always
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
      - "5001:5001"
 
    depends_on:
      - db-server
    networks:
      - localdev

    volumes:
      - $USERPROFILE/.aspnet/https:/https/

    environment:
        ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password: "Passw0rd!"
        ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path: "$USERPROFILE/.aspnet/https/aspnetapp.pfx"
    
  db-server:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: db-server
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=Password! 
    ports: 
      - "13306:3306" 
    networks: 
      - localdev
```

docker-compose log is here:

```
main-api     | warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[60]
main-api     |       Storing keys in a directory '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.
main-api     | crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
main-api     |       Unable to start Kestrel.
main-api     | Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file
main-api     |    at Interop.Crypto.CheckValidOpenSslHandle(SafeHandle handle)
main-api     |    at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.OpenSslX509CertificateReader.FromFile(String fileName, SafePasswordHandle password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
main-api     |    at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(String fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
main-api     |    at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(String fileName, String password)
main-api     |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.LoadCertificate(CertificateConfig certInfo, String endpointName)
main-api     |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.LoadDefaultCert(ConfigurationReader configReader)
main-api     |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.Load()
main-api     |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.ValidateOptions()
main-api     |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
main-api exited with code 0
```

```
$ ls -l %USERPROFILE%\.aspnet\https\aspnetapp.pfx
-rw-r--r-- 1 tig28 197609 2652 Dec 17 23:07 %USERPROFILE%.aspnethttpsaspnetapp.pfx
```

Using Linux syntax:

```
$ ls -l $USERPROFILE/.aspnet/https/aspnetapp.pfx
-rw-r--r-- 1 tig28 197609 2652 Dec 17 11:15 'C:\Users\tig28/.aspnet/https/aspnetapp.pfx'
```

Comment: What does this have to do with docker-compose?

Comment: See if you get the same error just using docker commands with your Dockerfile

Comment: `ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path` should only contain the valid file path. Please remove the invalid portion from it.

Comment: If I change the path to only a path I get the same no such file:  ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path: "%USERPROFILE%\\.aspnet\\https\\aspnetapp.pfx"

Comment: Based on the output you pasted above, you are trying to build a Linux Docker image, where Windows only environment variables such as %USERPROFILE% are usually invalid.

Comment: The cert is local on the windows machine.  I guess the problem is that the MS doc is incomplete and doesn’t give context.  The default path probably needs mounting but again is missing info on where.

Answer (score 1):

Minor change to your docker-compose file, here path will be your mounted path for the container `/root/.aspnet/https/ApiHost.pfx`.

```
environment:
  ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT: 6001
  ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development
  ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path:/root/.aspnet/https/ApiHost.pfx
  ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password: <password>
volumes:
  - ${USERPROFILE}\.aspnet\https:/root/.aspnet/https
```

Answer (score 0):

If your project uses .net 6 then local path to map to volume as shown below

Reference: [Hosting ASP.NET Core images with Docker Compose over HTTPS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-compose-https?view=aspnetcore-6.0#windows-using-linux-containers)

```
dotnet dev-certs https -ep %USERPROFILE%\.aspnet\https\aspnetapp.pfx -p { password here }
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

```yaml
version: '3.4'

services:
  webapp:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/samples:aspnetapp
    ports:
      - 80
      - 443
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=<password>
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
    volumes:
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
```